# How do I criss cross two lists together in python?

Tags: python, list

How do I criss cross two lists together in python?
Example:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

Expected Outcome:

```
combined_list = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Comment: What's the behavior if the two lists are not of the same length?

Comment: Then it doesn't work.

Comment: I want it only to work if the lists are the same length

Comment: What do you want to happen if they aren't the same length?

Comment: Then I want nothing to happen.

Comment: I explained why the question is not a duplicate so any reason that it's still downvoted?

Comment: It's a very similar question, however, I did update my answer to return an empty list if the two lists are not the same length.

Comment: Can you upvote chrisz since I explained my question?

Comment: @MrGenuis777 Please don't solicit votes here. If your question shows merit, it will be upvoted automatically.

Comment: I understand Coldspeed

Comment: It's just that I put effort into the question

Comment: Where is the effort? 2 lines of input, and one line of output. No semblance of what you've tried, your code, or any indication that you searched for this problem before asking a question...

Comment: Furthermore, you demand code of users: "I want code", sounds selfish, regardless of your intent.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is not my intent

Comment: And also I did search for this problem for like 15 minutes and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pythonic way of doing this:

```
[item for sublist in zip(a,b) for item in sublist]
```

Per the request, if you only want a list if the two lists are the same length, you can use:

```
[item for sublist in zip(a,b) for item in sublist if len(a) == len(b)]
```

And see if the result is an empty list.

Answer (score 4):

```
l = []
for x,y in zip(list_1,list_2):
    l.append(x)
    l.append(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [4, 5, 6]

new_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list_1,list_2))) 
# [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```